# Clearing recent icons

Tags: content-editor

I have an icon in my recents icons that has a FQDN for the path. It causes my icon picker to stall while the editor waits to resolve the url.

Does anyone know how to clear the recent icons list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recent icons are remembered for every user in their registry.

You can use `Registry.SetString("/Current_User/RecentIcons", string.Empty)` code to clean them.

Below is the code of a simple aspx file you can drop to your web application which will do the trick.

**IMPORTANT** put this file in `/sitecore/shell` folder. I've tried in website root directly and in `/sitecore/admin` and it didn't work for me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<script runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry.SetString("/Current_User/RecentIcons", string.Empty);
}
</script>
<html>
 <body>
  <p>Recent icons cleared.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

I've written a blog post describing how you can work with Sitecore Registry and with simple [Sitecore Registry Editor](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-registry-editor) application.

Comment: @ChrisAuer you may want to see https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-registry-editor